# How to make Canon 500D as IR camera?

Tags: canon, canon-500d, infrared, infrared-conversion

I want to make my Canon 500D as IR camera as I am getting a new camera. Can it be done DIY? or where can i get it done? and how much I should expect to pay ? I live in Durham, England.

Or I shouldn't? I read some posts saying Canon is not very good for IR. Is it true?

Thanks.

L

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you *can* do it yourself, but more risky work than I'd prefer! I can't speak on whether it's worth it or not.

If you've got basic tools already, you can get the IR filter for around US$180.

There are detailed instructions for the 500D [here](http://www.lifepixel.com/tutorials/infrared-diy-tutorials/canon-drebel-t1i-ir).

[This site](http://shop.lifepixel.com/6-Infrared-sensor-filters/Canon-Infrared-hot-mirror-replacement-filter-p1.html) is selling the filter for US$180.  I'd look around though, I'm sure you can find it for cheaper.  Do check up on quality though.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can convert the camera yourself but it's a complicated procedure that involves dismantling a lot of the camera. Unless you've done anything similar before I wouldn't advise it.

There are two companies I know of in the UK, Advanced Camera Services (whose website seems to have been hacked) and [ProTech](http://www.protechrepairs.co.uk/infrared_conversion.html). I had a 450D converted by ProTech and was very satisfied with the service. Conversion of an APS-C body costs £250.

What you've heard is sort of true. Canon lens coatings transmit less infrared than Nikons, which make Nikon lenses slightly better for IR work overall, however any lens used for infrared is operating well outside of it's design parameters and performance is unpredictable.

Ultimately you need to try a few lenses and see what results you get. The good news is that there are some very cheap lenses that perform better in infrared than their much more expensive top of the range counterparts.